# Google Cast iOS Cannot load media

Tags: ios, google-chrome, google-cast, google-cast-sdk

I've been having trouble making Google Cast SDK work properly for a week now. I have successfully established a connection with Chromecast receiver, at least the logs say so in so does my *GCKSessionManagerListener*.

This is how far my application flow gets at the moment:

- I start a live stream video in AVPlayer (u3m8 format)
- Wait for Google Cast button to become visible on the navigation bar
- Then I select my Chromecast receiver.

On SessionManagerListener - didStart (connection has been established) I request loadMedia on currentCastSession of SessionManager, I also tried loading queues, audio, image, nothing triggers Default Receiver App to appear. I hope someone will find a flaw in code/logic. 
This is all the relevant code:

Initialize on Application start:

```
let options = GCKCastOptions(discoveryCriteria:
    .init(applicationID: kGCKDefaultMediaReceiverApplicationID))
GCKCastContext.setSharedInstanceWith(options)
GCKLogger.sharedInstance().delegate = self
```

Building button:

```
    let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 24, height: 24)
    let castButton = GCKUICastButton(frame: frame)
    castButton.tintColor = UIColor.white
    return UIBarButtonItem(customView: castButton)
```

On my SessionManagerListener ->

```
func sessionManager(_ sessionManager: GCKSessionManager, didStart session: GCKSession) {
    let mediaInfo = GCKMediaInformation(contentID: url, streamType: .live,
        contentType: "video/m3u", metadata: nil, adBreaks: nil,
        adBreakClips: nil, streamDuration: .infinity,
        mediaTracks: nil, textTrackStyle: nil, customData: nil)

    print("loading media: \(String(describing: mediaInfo))")

    let request = sessionManager.currentCastSession?
        .remoteMediaClient?.loadMedia(mediaInfo)
    request?.delegate = self
}
```

I have simply run out of ideas and I'm turning to you guys for help, thank you all for your time!

Comment: The best is to start with one of the sample apps: https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-ios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems the code was fine and the Chromecast device was faulty. After replacing the device all previous requests started to go through without issues. Except for the unsupported files of course.